# The child component properties are getting overlapped. Don't know why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am new to Angular. Tried to make a button/badge component. But when I am trying to use it more than one time, the css are getting overlapped and misbehaving. I think that when new instance of the badge component got created the second time, it overwrote on the first one, not sure.

app.html

```
<div class="container">
  <app-badge [title]="'First'" [bgColor]="'Green'"></app-badge>
  <app-badge [title]="'Second'" [bgColor]="'Blue'"></app-badge>
</div>
```

badge.html

```
<div class="container">
    {{title}}
</div>
```

badge.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-badge',
  templateUrl: './badge.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./badge.component.css']
})
export class BadgeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  title : String="Badge";
  @Input()
  bgColor : String="";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    const ele = (document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]);
    ele.setAttribute("style", `background-color:${this.bgColor};`);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the result, and the css file for badge and for the parent component? Also maybe the container class has some weird css that causes the problem

Comment: the last @Input() with no variable, I assume is a typo?

Comment: @HarisBouchlis yeah, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's exactly what is happening like you explained, when second `app-badge` is rendered it will also overwrite the first one's background to blue.

First `app-badge` is rendered as `Green`.
Then second `app-badge` is rendered as `Blue`.

When second blue `app-badge` is rendered you are effectively saying this: Take the first `[0]` element from `container` and set this background to `this.bgColor` which is Blue. So now the first `app-badge` which is green turns to blue and now their both blue.

```js
 const ele = (document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]);
 ele.setAttribute("style", `background-color:${this.bgColor};`);
```

I suggest you to remove document manipulation altogether:

```js
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    const ele = (document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]);
    ele.setAttribute("style", `background-color:${this.bgColor};`);
  }
```

And change the color in `badge.component.html` using `NgStyle` (I don't know what you have in there, but it would go something like this):

```html
<div [style.background-color]="bgColor">
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: Got it thanks @Joosep! I later figured it out that ngStyle is the goto solution. Thanks anyways for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your setting the background color for the first element with class name `container` here

```
const ele = (document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0]);
```

So in your example the div that contains both badges is painted blue, while the badges do not have background colors, since only the first element with class `container` in the DOM is selected every time.

To fix it update your badge.ts to remove `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-badge',
  templateUrl: './badge.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./badge.component.css'],
})
export class BadgeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  title: String = 'Badge';

  @Input()
  bgColor: String = '';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

and your badge.html to apply the bgColor using `ngStyle`:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': bgColor }">
  {{ title }}
</div>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mqc4d6?file=src/app/badge/badge.component.html)